# could we detect if we reach the top list or bottom using ScrollablePositionedList.builder instead of ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollable

ok i decided to use
`ScrollablePositionedList.builder`
https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

instead of `ListView.builder`for more controlling of the index navigation ..

we know that `ScrollablePositionedList.builder` use `ItemScrollController()` instead of `ScrollController()`

using `ScrollController()` we can do the following to detect if we reach the top list or bottom

```
ScrollController scrollController= ScrollController(); 

     scrollController.addListener(() {
          if(scrollController.position.atEdge){
            if (scrollController.position.pixels == 0) {
              ///we arrive to the end        
              }
            }else{
             ///we arrive to the top
            }
          }
        });
```

but how could i do the same with using `ScrollablePositionedList.builder` that use `ItemScrollController()`

so i tried to do this

```
    ItemScrollController scrollController = ItemScrollController(); 
  final listener = ItemPositionsListener.create();
    
       listener.itemPositions.addListener(() {
          listener.itemPositions.value // here all what i get .. i cannot see any 
         position.atEdge or pixels like normal ScrollController
        });
```

really does it not support the detection of top list or bottom or something went wrong with me ?
thanks

Comment: Are you using this - https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

Comment: Yes ... exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check

- if the value of `itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.value.first.index` is 0

to say it is on top. And to check

- if the value of `${itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.value.last.index}` = list.length - 1

to say it reaches the bottom.

```dart
    itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.addListener(() {
      print(
          '====current first ${itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.value.first.index}====');
      print(
          '====current last ${itemPositionsListener.itemPositions.value.last.index}====');
    });
```

Comment: thanks it sound good idea , but i noticed it not exacttly at the top or bottom .. it will outputs once the item visible and not exactly till the end

Comment: @Jack You are right, the description to `itemPositions` is `The position of items that are at least partially visible in the viewport.`.  I cannot find a better solution currently sorry for that